# TeXShop gives "(null) does not exist" error when compiling postscript

Tags: errors, texshop

Mac: 10.7.3

TeXShop version: 2.47

When I try to compile .tex into a Post Script file, TeXShop gives me an error as follows:

> (null) does not exist. Perhaps TeXLive was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to the TeXShop web site and follow the instructions to (re)install TeXLive. Another possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using the fink teTeX distribution.

I can compile PDFs fine though. I don't remember updating TeXShop recently, so have no idea what's going on. Though I almost never compile to PS, so not sure if this problem is new either. Found a [post](http://sparemytie.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/texshop-cant-find-required-tool-null-does-not-exist/) suggesting I delete the preference file, but that doesn't work. If not a solution to this problem, does anybody know which script it is looking for and how to run it from command line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Open the TeXShop preferences and click on the Engine tab, and then in the part that says "TeX + dvips + distiller" click on the two default buttons (one for TeX and one for LaTeX).  Then try again.  Do you still get the error?

Comment: @Lena Please let us know what Alan's suggestion reveals. If there is no more info then the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I really wish this hadn't been closed....